# Convert results of API listing showing UNIX ENOCH time to human time

Tags: php, json, unix, epoch, phprunner

I use PHP Runner to get data using REST  API. The dates are showing as UNIX EPOCH Numbers. I need to show as human dates.

I can change the appearance using a custom view:
$value - a value to be displayed on the page.
Example:

```
$value = strtoupper($value);
```

$data - array with all field values.
Example:

```
$value = $data["FirstName"].$data["LastName"];
```

where FirstName and LastName are actual field names.

Just not sure how to add the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how both snippets of code you've provided here are at all related to the core of your question regarding dates expressed as Unix timestamps? [ask]

Comment: Agreed. What do first and last names have to do with times? There are no proper details in the question, and the only ones which _are_ present don't seem to relate to the title or the first paragraph. Does `$data` also contain these dates, in another field, perhaps? Show an example of the source data, and also an example of the output you want to achieve.

Comment: Before you do that though, please [read this](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+format+unix+timestamp+as+date) - you might find there is already an answer to your basic question. It's slightly unclear where you're stuck, though.